# Disable next button in Visual Studio setup project

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-installer

I have a setup project in Visual Studio it has more than 5 pages. From a specific page I two radio buttons where users carefully choose one. In current case most users select the default one. But what I need is there is no radio button is selected and the next button also disabled. On selection of correct radio option only the next button should be enabled. How can I do it only from Visual studio? (without going to WIX or Orca)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio simply doesn't expose what you are looking for.  The only way to do it without going to WiX or Orca is to use postbuild commands to run a utility to programmatically update the MSI to rewrite the ControlEvent table to behave the way you want.  You'll probably have to spend some time in ORCA to learn what that should look like.

Sorry, you can't get there from here using VDPROJ.